# mkdir writing permissions

Tags: php, codeigniter, mkdir

I have a small problem. I have searched stack overflow for similar things, but they don't seem to help (as far as I can tell).

I am using `mkdir` in `php`, which is working lovely and creating a new directory each month. However I have just noticed after the month changed that the directories are being created without write permissions. I believe this is to do with using 0777 to allow max access rights, however with this there is no change, and I believe this is set as default with out.

Here is the code:

```
if (!is_dir($this->config->item('rootpath').'/assets/documents/'.$date))
{
  $subDirectory = mkdir($this->config->item('rootpath').'/assets/documents/'.$date, 0777);
}
else
  $subDirectory = $this->config->item('rootpath').'/assets/documents/'.$date;
```

It is only after trying to upload a file, that the permission is denied, and I can go and set write permissions for the folder generated, and resubmit the file upload.

Comment: This may have to do with your umask. Try $oldumask = umask(0);
mkdir('your_dir', 0777); umask($oldumask);

Answer (score 2):

Add right permissions next to `mkdir` like this:

```
$subDirectory = mkdir( $this->config->item( 'rootpath' ) . '/assets/documents/' . $date, 0777 );
```

Comment: This is what i mean. I have started off with this, however I believe without it written, it defaults to 0777 anyway. Even with this or 0755 at the end, the folders are being created with read only?

Comment: It does not, for me, personally, without showing permissions, I get 644 + if your folders had 777 permission, you wouldn't have problems writing in them.

Comment: Ok fair enough. However assume my code now contains this exactly where you have put it and there is no change...this is whats happening. So I feel the problem lies elsewhere....

Comment: I have set the error messages to show on this bit of code....   $temp_file_location = $subDirectory.'/'.$thisServerFileName;
        
       if (!move_uploaded_file($_FILES["filename"]["tmp_name"], $temp_file_location))
        {
        $body_data['error'][]      = "File could not be moved due to a permissions error.";
         
        unlink($_FILES['filename']['tmp_name']);
        }

Comment: however when i manually go and change the permissions after folder is created, uploading is fine.

Comment: oooo yes. its all golden. Im befuddled.

Comment: And what does server log says?

Comment: I am unsure of server log stuff??

Comment: Well, you have written yourself, that there is a permission problems, but that doesn't mean it really is. You need to look up at php errors or server error log, to make sure, why exactly you can't upload a file to an existing directory with 777 rights...